# Macbook Pro (15-inch, Mid 2010) - Mini Displayport to HDMI **Does not work**

Tags: macbook-pro, hdmi, displayport

MacBook Pro (15-inch, Mid 2010). I'm trying to put it on another monitor through an HDMI adapter. As I'm not able to display the image on the other monitor, the Macbook screen simply blinks when I plug the HDMI adapter into the DisplayPort output. I already tested 2 different adapters and all have the same result.

I also have a Mini DisplayPort to VGA adapter, and it works normally.

Using macOS Sierra Version 10.12.3;

What could be going wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: What brand adaptor are you using? My business has found that many Mini DisplayPort > HDMI adaptors are not up to Apple spec and either work poorly or don't work at all. We did the research so you don't have to. :-) The **Belkin** branded MDP > HDMI adaptor @ [Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/Belkin-Displayport-Thunderbolt-Adapter-Black/dp/B00COEBCXY). works just fine  _Disclaimer: I have no financial ties to either Belkin or Amazon.com._